# GitLab pipeline stopped working (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

My GitLab pipeline used to work perfectly, but now I get the following error:

```
$ git config --global user.email "${GIT_USER_EMAIL:-$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}"
$ git config --global user.name "${GIT_USER_NAME:-$GITLAB_USER_NAME}"
$ git clone git@gitlab.com:my_repo_url
$ python folder/run.py
$ cp *.pdf folder/Guides || echo "No pdfs found"
$ cd folder
$ git add *.pdf
$ git commit -m "${CI_PROJECT_NAME} - ${CI_COMMIT_TITLE}" || echo "No changes to commit"
[main 29197a2] proj_name - update title
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 Guides/proj_name.pdf
$ git push origin -o ci.skip || echo "Push failed"
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
To gitlab.com:my_repo_url
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:my_repo_url'
Push failed
```

No settings changes have been made to the repo. `main` branch is not protected.

I have tried to checkout another branch and commit to that but received exactly the same error.

What else should I try?

Comment: `You are not allowed to push code to this project.`  `What else should I try?` you should try authorizing yourself with a generated deploy token with proper permission to push to the repo.

Comment: @KamilCuk that has already been done (using deploy key) - this used to work and nothing changed...

Comment: @Leo I think you cannot push using deploy key, deploy keys only allow clone/fetch/pull.

Comment: @phd - it used to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the deploy key used was created by someone who is no longer a member of the repo.

I created a new key, set it up with my user, and that fixed it.

The docs stated [Public deploy key: Access can be granted to any project in a GitLab instance. Access to each project must be granted by a user with at least the Maintainer role.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/) but I failed to understand that the key is bound to the user who registers it.